# How to trigger keydown events on Ng Select DropDown - Get ng select panel in code behind

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am using ng select:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

StackBlitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvo39c?file=src%2Fforms-with-options-example.component.ts

I want to be able to highlight an object in the `Listbox` with arrows `UP` or `DOWN` and then have the highlighted item `selected` when pressing arrow `RIGHT` or `LEFT`.

I have tried to do this using event `keydownInDropdown` and event `onDropDownChange`. 
`keydownInDropdown`is fired before `onDropDownChange`.

Another solution that would work for me:
Highlighting an object in the `Listbox` with arrows `UP` or `DOWN` and then select the object when clicking `enter` the first time.
Second time clicking `enter` if no changes the dropdown should close.

Comment: Can you add stackblitz?

Comment: could you please tell did my answer worked or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working whole day came up with following solution. When you click right or left arrow keys while selecting options it will be selected.(you can replace whole code in your stackblitz. I made it for single select you can also make it for multi-select based on your requirement.)

**component.html code**

```
<form [formGroup]="heroForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <ng-select [virtualScroll]="false" [multiple]="false"  [keyDownFn]="keydownInDropdown" 
       (keydown)="makeChoice($event)" #ngSelect
      > // taking its reference by #ngSelect & calling "makeChoice" method when any keyboard clicks are happening.
     // there is no need of ngModel so i removed it from the code.

          <ng-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.id" 

          >{{car.name}}</ng-option>
          <ng-option [value]="'custom'">Custom</ng-option>
      </ng-select>
      <br/>Selected car ID: {{selectedCars | json}}

    </div>

</div>
```

**component.ts code**

```
import { Component, OnInit,ElementRef,HostListener,ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'forms-with-options-example',
  templateUrl: './forms-with-options-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./forms-with-options-example.component.scss']
})
export class FormsWithOptionsExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder,private el:ElementRef) {
  }


  @ViewChildren('ngSelect') ngSelect:ElementRef;

  selectedCars = [3];
  cars = [
   { id: 1, name: 'Volvo' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Saab' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Opel' },
   { id: 4, name: 'Audi' },
  ];

  keydownInDropdown(event)
   {
     if (event.keyCode == 13)
     {
       // set highlighted value as selected value. (default)
       console.log(event);
     }

     if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39)
     {
       // set highlighted value as selected value.
       console.log(event);
     }
     // console.log("keydown is ",event)
   }
   ngOnInit() {

   }


   makeChoice(e) {

      if(e.key==='ArrowRight' || e.key==='ArrowLeft') {

        var totalOptions = this.ngSelect["first"].dropdownPanel.contentElementRef.nativeElement.children;
        console.log("total opetions are ",totalOptions);
        var i;

        for(i=0;i<totalOptions.length;i++) {

            if(totalOptions[i].classList.value.includes('ng-option-marked')) {
             // console.log("selected index is ",i);
             this.selectedCars = i;
             totalOptions[i].click();

            }
         }

      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Have updated my description and a stackblitz. Your solution could solve what I had described. Though my description was not good enough.

Comment: This one worked and has the expected outcome! Thanks for the effort! :)